# I have installed pil with conda but when I try to import it, it says no module exists

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, conda

[image]

I have installed pil with conda but when I try to import it, it says no module exists.

Comment: `pil` should be an uppercase `PIL`, try doing `from PIL import Image`, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to import the module in uppercase?

```
In [3]: import pil
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2fdcc9532329> in <module>()
----> 1 import pil

ImportError: No module named pil

In [4]: import PIL

In [5]: PIL
Out[5]: <module 'PIL' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.pyc'>
```